# Angular 2 and google closure

Tags: angularjs, google-closure, google-closure-library

I know this question is off topic. But I think it would be hot topic.

Google has two Web UI project, both Angular 2 and Google closure. Could someone give hints if we want to develope data centric application which tool we shall use, Angular 2 or Google closure?

Your answer are highly appreciated.

[2016/April/11] added:

I mean Closure Library. Mostly many of our UI components are Grid. Our developers are Java developers，they are not that good at Javascript. Could we make Grid UI or other UI,   (http://dekajp.github.io/demos/index.html) into some template, then render template into Java?

Comment: Google closure is a tool, but Angular 2 is not a tool, it is a framework.

Comment: Do you mean Closure Library or Closure Compiler?

Comment: @John I mean Closure Library. Mostly many of our UI components are Grid.